# How to set my ios app language to arabic?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

Below is the code which I am using to set the language of my app, Some how I am unable to find the correct value for AppleLanguages. Can some one please guide me, where can I get the list of values for AppleLanguages?

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"arabic"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Here is the code (as shown on the previous tutorial) http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. The first link has got a nice tutorial but it needs iphone to change its default language,which I don't want user to do.

Answer (score 0):

Do this really early in your app, like in your main() function.

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"ar"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```